# Palindromes and exclamation points - Java

Tags: java, string, palindrome

I have an assignment in which I'm supposed to detect whether or not a string is a palindrome. The program is supposed to recognize non-alphanumeric characters and ignore case (eg. "a" and "A" are the same). One of the strings is `" !  "` (space, !, space, space) and every time I try to set everything in the string to lower case, the "!" gets completely deleted for some reason. I've tried the following:

```
String string = " !  ";
string = string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+","").toLowerCase(); 
//when converted into an array, the array is empty
```

Is there a way to handle this case? Many thanks!

Edit:  from the comments, I just figured out it says "replace anything not in the alphabet". Sorry about that. I haven't learned a lot about regexes yet, so my bad.

Comment: Well, you're obviously replacing any non alphabetic character with an empty `String`, what do you expect?

Comment: Can you expalin, in words, what `string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+","")` does?

Comment: You regex basically says "If the character is not a-z or A-Z, remove it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> every time I try to set everything in the string to lower case, the "!" gets completely deleted for some reason.

You wrote:

```
string = string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+","").toLowerCase();
```

The method `String#replaceAll` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)) replaces all characters that match the given regex expression by the given character, you use `""` (empty text) for substitution, that is you delete matching characters.

The regex expression

```
[^a-zA-Z]+
```

matches every character that is **not** `a-z` (`a` to `z`) **nor** `A-Z` (`A` to `Z`). The `+` sign repeats the pattern, it matches for *1 to infinitely many*.

In words this means you **delete** every **non alphabetic character**. That is why your string, after replacing, is empty (`_` denotes `space`):

```
Before: _!__
After:
```

For details to the regex expression, take a look at [regex101/TNfQcO](https://regex101.com/r/TNfQcO/1). They explain the expression word by word. Here are some examples, everything in blue is matched and will be deleted by your expression:

[image: regex101 screenshot showing some examples]

---

For palindromes check out one of many equivalent questions like

- [Check string for palindrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome)
- [Java Palindrome checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36534673/java-palindrome-checker)
- [Java- Palindrome Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115900/java-palindrome-program)

Comment: I would add that the best way to ignore the case of the string is to use the String.toLowerCase() method. No need for any regex here